# Install VLC on Windows 7 x64

Tags: installation, 64-bit, vlc-media-player, x86

How Can I install VLC on an x64 bit version of **Windows 7**?

[image]

I have checked the compatibility modes and I do not see an x86 version. I have tried running is under XP and Vista with no luck.

Comment: I've never heard of this being an issue. It works fine for me. You should not have to set any compatibility mode. Did you try simply redownloading it?

Comment: @oKtosiTe: Interesting, thank you for sharing. I am using an AMD chip, not sure if that would cause a problem. I have tried re-downloading with the same results.

Comment: I'm using an AMD Athlon 64 X2 myself.

Comment: I assume you're on the final retail version of Windows 7?

Comment: I am using a retail version!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a weird error since I am running VLC on win 7 x64 and I think I used the regular binary installer. Have you tried the zipped version on the download page?

Comment: I just downloaded the zipped version and it works fine. However, when I re-download and attempt to install from the installer I get the same error.

Comment: Well I am happy it "installed". I will accept in 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, compile from source!